# How to put $_POST attribute to httpost and how to send object with list to PHP (JSON)

Tags: php, android, json, http-post

I am working on an app for Android OS. There is one thing, I do not know how to do.
I need to send information to PHP web service (which I have created).

My question (first is easier, but I did not find any answer).
I have found somewhere this

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(address);
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

It works, because address includes the GET information. I would like to ask, how, or where to put `$_POST` information.
I mean, in PHP I will check if (isset($_POST['name']) - so where to put that "name"??
I have one php where i am checking which post is set.

My second question is, I would like to send information to PHP web which is like Object.

```
Student student = new Student (String name, .. );
Class class = new Class(long id, String name, int floor, List<Students>);
```

I would like to send to php service the "class" object, which contains list of objects.

I was thinking, I can send the class attributes and than the list as some other post (just an array of students for example).
I don't know much JSON, but I think, it will be something with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost ht = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.208/moodle/demo.php");
List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
```

add the variables and their values like this

```
nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("variable", "value-to-pass"));
```

got it.

```
UrlEncodedFormEntity uefe = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp, HTTP.UTF_8);
ht.setEntity(uefe);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(ht);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
String result="";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    sb.append(line + "\n");
result = sb.toString();
is.close();
```

Sorry but i don't know the answer to the second question.. :(